# Determine all columns used to execute some SQL on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have hundreds of SQL Server stored procedures and script files, and I need to determine for each one the exact tables and columns they use. This is not easily done as the SQL is complicated and many of the tables have columns with the same names etc...

I found the SQL below which for a stored procedure will tell me what tables it uses, however I need to get down to column level and have hit a blank.

Does anyone have any SQL script which will achieve this, or in fact some .NET code would also be fine as we can weave this in with a little application.

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) AS referencing_entity_name, 
    o.type_desc AS referencing_desciption, 
    COALESCE(COL_NAME(referencing_id, referencing_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referencing_minor_id, 
    referencing_class_desc, referenced_class_desc,
    referenced_server_name, referenced_database_name, referenced_schema_name,
    referenced_entity_name, 
    COALESCE(COL_NAME(referenced_id, referenced_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referenced_column_name,
    is_caller_dependent, is_ambiguous
FROM 
    sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed
INNER JOIN 
    sys.objects AS o ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id
WHERE 
    referencing_id = OBJECT_ID(N'MySchenma.MyStoredProcedure');
```

Comment: Have you considering dumping all procedures to files and writing a small script to list filename, table(s) and column(s) from there instead of through a sql query?

Comment: i think that script would be quite a pain to write, as it would need to deal with aliases and tie together where everything hasn't been coded 100% explicitly. E.g. '  SELECT t.SystemID
   ,t.EntityID
   ,t.ExtractDate
   ,t.FinYear
   ,a.CoAID
   ,a.AccountNum
   ,a.AccountSubNum
   ,FinPeriod
   ,Movement
  INTO #tb
  FROM Core.TrialBalance t
  JOIN Core.Account a
   ON t.AccountID = a.AccountID
  WHERE t.FinPeriod > 0  '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct
  object_name(objs.referencing_id) as referencing_entity_name,
  cols.referenced_entity_name,
  cols.referenced_minor_name
from
  sys.sql_expression_dependencies objs
  outer apply sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities( OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objs.referencing_id) + N'.' + object_name(objs.referencing_id), N'OBJECT' ) as cols
where
  objs.referencing_id = object_id(N'MySchenma.MyStoredProcedure')
order by
  object_name(objs.referencing_id)
  cols.referenced_entity_name,
  cols.referenced_minor_name
;
```

Comment: @TacticalSolutions That was a part of a bigger query, and I left it as is because in this form it's easier to integrate it into another query and/or return information about multiple referencing objects. Otherwise you could just do `select ... from sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(N'MySchenma.MyStoredProcedure')`.

Comment: Already re-jiged it into 4 useful sprocs for the team, so it told me all i needed. /tip_hat